# Jquery variables - can't calculate with a number var

Tags: jquery, css, variables, math, height

Hi I'm new to this so this might be a rookie jquery question...

I'm trying to define a line height by using the below method:

```
var line_height = $('.container').css("height"); 
console.log(line_height); 
$('.vertical-line').height(line_height-1000);
```

But for some reason I cannot calculate `line_height-1000` when line_height is clearly a number variable (I checked with `console.log`). `line_height-1000 returns NaN` instead.

Any type of help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I tried several workarounds but none of them worked...

option 1:

```
var line_height = $('.container').css("height"); 
$('.vertical-line').height(line_height);
```

option 2:

```
var line_height = $('.container').css("height"); 
var h = line_height - 1000; $('.vertical-line').height(h);
```

option 3:

```
var line_height = $('.container').css("height")-1000; 
$('.vertical-line').height(line_height);
```

Comment: It says NaN because line_height = 0px. you are doing something like 0px * 123 string * number.

Answer (score 0):

It says NaN because line_height = 0px. you are doing something like 0px * 123 (string * number).

```
var line_height = $(".container").height();
var h = line_height - 1000;
$(".vertical-line").height(h);
```

Comment: Oh man thank you so much! It makes sense now. I'm going to use parseInt to get the actual value.